# Split or not a test case with PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, testing

I am using Laravel 8 and learning the testing.

Let's say I want to test that the policies on a resource are OK. I have tried this :

```
public function testGetOrganizations(): void
    {
        $organizations = Organization::factory()->count(10)->create();
        $this->actingAsRole('SUPERADMIN', null);
        $this->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')->assertStatus(200);

        $this->actingAsRole('ADMIN', $organizations[0]->id);
        $this->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')->assertStatus(403);

        $this->actingAsRole('EMPLOYEE', $organizations[0]->id);
        $this->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')->assertStatus(403);
    }
```

It works fine. But I wonder if it should be better if I split this test in 3 parts:

- a test for the role "SUPERADMIN"
- a test for the role "ADMIN"
- a test for the role "EMPLOYEE"

I am afraid that if I split, then the class will be longer and perhaps more complicated to maintain and understand. What is a good practice for this case?

Comment: So in general a test should test one functionality. Now one could argue that each role has another functionality aspect. You could make folders for each role and a general one and then split up your tests in this way. 
But most of the time, the role testing is about the right of access, so I would keep the tests in one file and maybe make diffrent  methods if the functionality has large changes or needs much work.

Answer (score 1):

Better to implement this as 3 separate test cases with some meaningful names. Following is the way which I prefer because the name itself describes the functionality and easy to understand for someone else also.

```
 /**
 * @test
 */
public function superadmins_should_be_able_to_see_organizations(): void
{
    Organization::factory()->count(10)->create();
    
    $this->actingAsRole('SUPERADMIN', null)
        ->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')
        ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK)
        ->assertCount(10);
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function admins_should_not_be_able_to_access_organizations(): void
{
    $organizations = Organization::factory()->count(10)->create();

    $this->actingAsRole('ADMIN', $organizations[0]->id)
        ->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')
        ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function employees_should_not_be_able_to_access_organizations(): void
{
    $organizations = Organization::factory()->count(10)->create();
    
    $this->actingAsRole('EMPLOYEE', $organizations[0]->id)
        ->json('GET', $this->getUrl() . '/organizations')
        ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
```